# Error saving Associated data cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am unable to save data by using cakephp 3 association

AddressHeadersTable

```
$this->hasMany('Addresses', [
            'foreignKey' => 'address_header_id'
        ]);
```

AddressesTable

```
$this->belongsTo('AddressHeaders', [
            'foreignKey' => 'address_header_id',
        ]);
```

Controller Code

```
$data = [
            'user_id' => 1,
            'company_id' => 4,
            'address' => [
                'user_id' => 1,
                'company_id' => 4,
                'name' => 'Aneh'
            ]
        ];

        $entity = $this->AddressHeaders->newEntity();
        $entity = $this->AddressHeaders->patchEntity($entity, $data, [
            'associated' =>['Addresses']
        ]);
        if($this->AddressHeaders->save($entity)){
            echo "save";
        }else{
            pr($entity->errors());
        }
```

We need to save multiple address under one address header id. when i run above code it create entery in address_header but did not make any entry in addresses table.

Answer (score 2):

Your data structure should be like this:

```
$data = [
    'user_id' => 1,
    'company_id' => 4,
    'addresses' => [
        [
            'user_id' => 1,
            'company_id' => 4,
            'name' => 'Aneh'
        ]
    ]
];
```

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-hasmany-associations

> When saving hasMany associations, the ORM expects an array of entities
>   named with the plural, underscored version of the association name

Comment: Thanks for reply but still data is not saving plz check sql log https://prnt.sc/ipz2mg

Comment: Your addresses needs to be in array ``'addresses' => [0 => $address1, 1 => $address2]]``

Comment: Hi plz check this gist https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3201973ab3ab52023829d66bd2d5ee2b is there any thing wrong you can track but still data is not save in address table

Comment: Please check my gist https://gist.github.com/shahonseven/866516b537791084d72593808e93d566. I have successfully save the data using your code.

Comment: Thanks for your time, I find my error it was due to the entity. Thanks